# Joining same table multiple times in ServiceStack.OrmLite

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

When joining a table to itself, the sql statment generated does not reference the tables correctly.

It's working when the "main" table is different from the joining table https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#join-aliases

**Class**

```
public class Page
{
    public string ActivityId { get; set; }
    public int DefinitionId { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
}
```

**Code**

```
using (var db = connection.Open())
{
    var sql = db.From<Page>()
     .Join<Page>((p1, p2) => 
       p1.DefinitionId == 349 && 
       p1.ActivityId == "a633326227969545457" && 
       p1.PageId == p2.PageId && 
       p2.DefinitionId == 340, db.JoinAlias("p2"))
     .Select<Page>(p => new {
            String = Sql.JoinAlias(p.ActivityId, "p2")
     });

}
```

**SQL statement**

**p1**.DefinitionId == 349 and **p1**.ActivityId == "a633326227969545457", these should not refer to **p2**

```
SELECT p2."ActivityId" AS String 
FROM "Page" INNER JOIN "Page" p2 ON (
    ((("p2"."DefinitionId" = 349) 
  AND ("p2"."ActivityId" = 'a633326227969545457')) 
  AND ("p2"."PageId" = "p2"."PageId")) 
  AND ("p2"."DefinitionId" = 340))
```

Is it a bug or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to use an alias on the source table you would need to set a table alias which wasn't supported until now with [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/1ef91856b87fe9127873b06c73b38fcbd0baf8d9).

You can now use the new `db.TableAlias()` API (which is now preferable over `JoinAlias()`) on both the source table as well as any join tables, e.g:

```
var q = db.From<Page>(db.TableAlias("p1"))
    .Join<Page>((p1, p2) => 
        p1.DefinitionId == 349 && 
        p1.ActivityId == "a633326227969545457" && 
        p1.PageId == p2.PageId && 
        p2.DefinitionId == 340, db.TableAlias("p2"))
    .Select<Page>(p => new {
        String = Sql.TableAlias(p.ActivityId, "p2")
    });

var rows = db.Select(q);
```

This change is available from v5.4.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: mythz I am using 5.4.1 and I get the error. 'TableOptions' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best extension method overload 'OrmLiteReadApi.Select<Company>(IDbConnection, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IDbConnection'

Comment: @SteveColeman sounds like your code is wrong, db.TableAlias() is only an argument and .Select() should only be called on the SqlExpression not TableAlias(). You can check out the commit for more usage examples.

Comment: :-( ... I was missing a )   It was a long day of coding. Thanks for the response.

Comment: How can I get this to work with SelectMulti?