# ServiceStack OrmLite SelectMulti same table

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

This is a bit related to this question: [Joining same table multiple times in ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53436421/joining-same-table-multiple-times-in-servicestack-ormlite)

`TableAlias` works with `Select`, but not `SelectMulti`.

Example:

```cs
var query = db.From<Department>(db.TableAlias("main"))
  .Where(main => main.DepLevel == 3)
  .Join<Department>((main, sub) => sub.DepParentNo == main.DepNo, db.TableAlias("sub"));
```

Now `var rows = db.Select(query);` works, but this crashes:

```cs
var queryResults = db.SelectMulti<Department, Department>(query);
```

I've confirmed that when using `db.Select` the `LastCommandText` correctly aliases all three tables. However it probably doesn't do that with `SelectMulti`.

The error message is as expected: *The column prefix 'Department' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.*

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here:

There's an example in SS's source code:

```cs
AssertTupleResults(db.SelectMulti<Sale, ContactIssue, ContactIssue>(q, 
    new[] { "Sale.*", "buyer.*", "seller.*" }));
```

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/1ba40ef4b77d9ae792a268f1683c51960d4476d6/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/Issues/MultipleSelfJoinsWithJoinAliases.cs#L216

So the expression is now:

```cs
var queryResults = db.SelectMulti<Department, Department>(query, 
    new[] { "main.*", "sub.*" });
```